# XRDP on upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: xrdp

Been struggling all day to get xrdp working.

The machine was running Ubuntu 16.04 which I upgraded to 18.04.

I have tried to set up XRDP using lots of approaches but all I get is the green xrdp screen when running RDP.

Not sure where to start ? Help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This green login screen is expected !

After installing the xRDP, you need to perform your remote connection.  You will end up in the xRDP login screen (green screen xrdp screenshot above).

- In the first line, select the **option Xorg**
- Then provide your username
- finally, provide you password

Press OK and if everything is ok, you will see a Gnome Desktop interface displayed in front of you

**! Note !**

We assume that you have performed a manual installation of xrdp using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp 
sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04  (if you are running Ubuntu 18.04.3 or later)
```

If this is the case, when connecting to Ubuntu remotely, you will see the basic Gnome desktop and not the custom Ubuntu Desktop with the Dock

If you want to automate and fix the small look'n feel discrepancies between your local desktop interface and remote interface,  you can use the following xrdp-installer-v1.x.sh script that help automate and perform post-configuration actions for you

Please use the script at your own risk and please review the howto guide provided before trying to run the script (see [http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093)

Hope this help

Till next time

See ya